# Showing icon side by side using CSS

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS.

I have the following CSS definition which shows an icon in my webpage.

```
.systemIcon{
    margin-right:2px;
    background:url(../images/tree/system.png?_v=001) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

I wanted to add another icon to its right (lets say system2.png).
So I tried the following:

```
.systemIcon{
    margin-right:2px;
    background:url(../images/tree/system.png?_v=001), url(../images/tree/system2.png?_v=001) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

But the result is that the icon show on **ON TOP** of the other.

Is there any way to show them **side by side**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `background-position` and `background-repeat` for each image:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/colorful-long-shadow/256/Home-icon.png'), url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/kyo-tux/aeon/256/Sign-LogOff-icon.png');
  background-position: 0px 0px, 256px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  width: 512px;
  height: 256px;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show icons, perhaps you should use multiple `<img/>` HTML tags. That seems preferable to the `background` CSS property.

Comment: Thanks, but I use ExtJs with their treepanel - of which I don't have control. That's why I would like to do it using the CSS...